# old elasticsearch log4j2 .gz files for logs will not delete on condition - Why?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j2, delete-file

I am troubleshooting an issue where the old log.gz and json.gz logs to delete based on the conditions the log4j2 properties is given. For testing I set it to 1 day. I am asking if anyone see anything wrong with what I have done here.
First the groundwork details so you know what is set up:

- I am in GCP, running a Rocky Linux 8.8 instance
- I am running elasticsearch 7.17.11 to mimic the prod environment, and running that on localhost for testing
- In my elasticsearch.yml I set path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
- The base_path in log4j2 properties resolve properly because I see the rollovers work just fine
- The permissions are set to elasticsearch (default)
- For testing only: I set SELinux to permissive (setenforce 0)
- I do systemctl restart elasticsearch after every change I make
- my cluster is named asa-test and the resulting log format after roll is asa-test-2023-08-03-1.json.gz and asa-test-2023-08-03-1.log.gz
- The following is the block of the log4j2.properties that is not working as I expect to delete the old logs.

Nothing works. What am I missing here? Why do the old .gz continue to persist?

```
######## Server JSON ############################
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = plain_rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}_server.json
appender.rolling.layout.type = ESJsonLayout
appender.rolling.layout.type_name = server

appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.json.gz
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.age = 1D
################################################
######## Server -  old style pattern ###########
appender.rolling_old.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling_old.name = rolling_old
appender.rolling_old.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}.log
appender.rolling_old.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling_old.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n

appender.rolling_old.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling_old.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling_old.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling_old.policies.size.size = 100MB
appender.rolling_old.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling_old.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.age = 1D
################################################
```

I have tried many variations to include:

- setting the basepath + globs explicitly
- different date formats to include -mm so I could target minutes and set the delete to 1m
- setting it to delete based on only filename only
- setting it with filename as the nested condition
- setting it the delete age as the only condition to 2D
- a wide variation of other glob patterns to try to capture the correct file.

I expected one of those steps to show me where the issue is. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `%d{...}` pattern in your glob:

```
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-*
```

While `${...}` lookups can be used in any value, the `%d{...}` pattern is only valid in the `filePattern` property of the appender and contains the file date of the log being archived.

The glob will therefore expand to a **literal** `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}`, which does **not** match any files.